# Retrieve specific dictionary of a larger one in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so I apologize is I confuse the terminology a bit...
I'm given the following dictionary:

```
[
   {
      "responseData":true,
      "requestClass":"MessageService",
      "requestMethod":"newMessage",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":{
         "time":1590429080,
         "__class__":"Time"
      },
      "requestClass":"TimeService",
      "requestMethod":"updateTime",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":[
         {
            "value":16,
            "type":"recruitment_acceleration",
            "__class__":"RecruitmentAccelerationBonus"
         },
         {
            "value":3,
            "type":"daily_strategypoint",
            "__class__":"DailyStrategyPointBonus"
         }
      ],
      "requestClass":"BonusService",
      "requestMethod":"getBonuses",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":{
         "resources":{
            "diplomacy":372,
            "brush":0,
            "marble":559
         },
         "__class__":"Resources"
      },
      "requestClass":"ResourceService",
      "requestMethod":"getPlayerResources",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   { # added missing bracket
      "responseData":[
         {
            "gridId":"main",
            "type":"antiquesExchange",
            "time":1590481057,
            "__class__":"Timer"
         }
      ],
      "requestClass":"TimerService",
      "requestMethod":"getTimers",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   }
]
```

And need to extract the part contained in the same array as the `requestMethod` named `getPlayerResources`, in the current case:

```
{
   "diplomacy":372,
   "brush":0,
   "marble":559
  }
```

I have tried multiple things with `find` or the sample below but never managed to get what I want.
The position of the `getPlayerResources` may not always be the same, which complicate things.

```
    def search(values, searchFor):
        for k in values:
            print (values)
            print (k)
            for v in values[k]:
                if searchFor in v:
                    return k
        return None


if '/game/json' in request.path:
            responsestring = request.response.body
            response_json_object = json.loads(responsestring)
            
            for object in response_json_object:
                for attribute, value in object.items():
                    if value != True and value != False:
                        result = search(value, 'getPlayerResources')
```

Comment: Also, when you say "the position of the `getPlayerResources` may not be the same", can you show the possible cases? I don't see why `next(x for x in data if x["requestMethod"] == "getPlayerResources")["responseData"]` isn't sufficient.

Comment: Correct, I have added the missing `{` which disappeared when I cleaned up the file when pasting here. Some of the answers given below are working. I will select one of them. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, pay attention that your json is not valid.

```
d = [
   {
      "responseData":True,
      "requestClass":"MessageService",
      "requestMethod":"newMessage",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":{
         "time":1590429080,
         "__class__":"Time"
      },
      "requestClass":"TimeService",
      "requestMethod":"updateTime",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":[
         {
            "value":16,
            "type":"recruitment_acceleration",
            "__class__":"RecruitmentAccelerationBonus"
         },
         {
            "value":3,
            "type":"daily_strategypoint",
            "__class__":"DailyStrategyPointBonus"
         }
      ],
      "requestClass":"BonusService",
      "requestMethod":"getBonuses",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
   {
      "responseData":{
         "resources":{
            "diplomacy":372,
            "brush":0,
            "marble":559
         },
         "__class__":"Resources"
      },
      "requestClass":"ResourceService",
      "requestMethod":"getPlayerResources",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   },
    {"responseData":[
         {
            "gridId":"main",
            "type":"antiquesExchange",
            "time":1590481057,
            "__class__":"Timer"
         }
      ],
      "requestClass":"TimerService",
      "requestMethod":"getTimers",
      "requestId":1,
      "__class__":"ServerResponse"
   }
]

for inner_d in d:
    if "requestMethod" in inner_d and inner_d["requestMethod"] == "getPlayerResources":
        print(inner_d["responseData"]['resources'])
```

The above code uses the fixed json and prints:

```
{'diplomacy': 372, 'brush': 0, 'marble': 559}
```

Answer (score 1):

The outermost character in that json is a square bracket, so this is a list of dicts.

```
# loop over all the dicts
for d in response_json_object:

    # is this the one we're looking for?
    if d.get("requestMethod") == "getPlayerResources":
        print("Found the data!")
        print(d["responseData"]["resources"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a dictionnary but a list of dictionnaries. Also, be aware that you must put a capital T to True in Python, otherwise your code won't work.

The following function will return the part you want to extract if you give it your list in argument:

```
def findResource(l):
    for d in l:
        if "requestMethod" in d and d["requestMethod"] == "getPlayerResources":
            return d["responseData"]["resources"]
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not been given a dictionnary, but a list of dict, json file.
First there is a '{' missing in line 51 of your file.

Once you have imported the json file, you can find the position of the dict you're looking for using a loop, and then get what you want:

```
import json
with open('p.json') as f:
    response_json_object = json.load(f)

position = []
for pos, elt in enumerate(response_json_object):
    if elt['requestMethod'] == 'getPlayerResources':
        position.append(pos)
    
response_json_object[position[0]]['requestMethod']
```

Should give you 'getPlayerResources'. position is a list so the [0] is there to get the number inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
res_dict = json.loads(responsestring)
for section in res_dict:
    if section['requestMethod'] == 'getPlayerResources':
        resources = section['responseData']['resources']
        print(resources)
        break
```

Output

```
{'diplomacy': 372, 'brush': 0, 'marble': 559}
```